# dynamically load the web page into jquery tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want dynamically load the content of a webpage as a tooltip using jquery.Is there any jquery plugging or mechanism to do it?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `load` function of jQuery library. See reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/). As well you can find an examples on same page.